# Inserting new customer into table using subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-insert

[image: Table]

Insert a customer Jake Smith whose shipping address is “yknhl fr hluhw”, he can be reached at ‘1236548780’ & ‘jakesmith@email.com’ (use a sub query to get the address from shipping_details table, direct insertion of address will be marked as incorrect).

^ the assignment question's instructions

[image: My failed attempt at understanding]

```
use assignment;   
insert into customers(first_name,last_name,email,phoneNo)    
values ('Jake','Smith','jakesmith@email.com','1236548780');
where shipping_detail_id in (select shipping_details.address from shipping_details where address like 'yknhl fr hluhw');
```

What am I doing wrong in line 4 so I can successfully add the new customer into the tables. I feel confused and not sure where to go from there

Comment: update your SQL scripts in this question itself rather than tagging a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A
s you can see in the [definition](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) of `ÌNSERT INTO`

There is no `WHERE` clause,  a UPDATE has one

But you can use

```
use assignment;   
insert into customers(first_name,last_name,email,phoneNo,shipping_detail_id)    
SELECT('Jake','Smith','jakesmith@email.com','1236548780', shipping_detail_id)
 from shipping_details where address like 'yknhl fr hluhw'
 LIMIT 1;
```

OR

```
use assignment;   
insert into customers(first_name,last_name,email,phoneNo,shipping_detail_id)    
VALUES ('Jake','Smith','jakesmith@email.com','1236548780', (SELECT shipping_detail_id
 from shipping_details where address like 'yknhl fr hluhw'
 LIMIT 1));
```

The `LIMIT 1` is in case that there are multiple ids for that adress, then you should add an `ORDER BY` to get the correct one

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! Looking at your SQL compared to mine I understand it better now